# Having problems with python's random.shuffle

Tags: python, matrix, random, permutation, shuffle

I would like to make a matrix whose lines are different permutations of the following vector=
[1,2,3,4,5,10,10,10,10,10]
I tried to use the random.shuffle function, but it seems that everytime I use that, It redefines all objects to which it is assigned. For example, I have tried the following:

```
vec=[1,2,3,4,5]  
for i in range(5):  
    vec.append(10)  
Matpreferences=[]  
for i in range(10):  
    random.shuffle(vec)  
    Matpreferences.append(vec)
```

But then I get a matrix with all lines equal.
eg:

```
[0, 0, 1.0, 0, 2.0, 3.0, 0, 0.5, 2.5, 1.5, 0]    
[0, 0, 1.0, 0, 2.0, 3.0, 0, 0.5, 2.5, 1.5, 0]  
[0, 0, 1.0, 0, 2.0, 3.0, 0, 0.5, 2.5, 1.5, 0]  
[0, 0, 1.0, 0, 2.0, 3.0, 0, 0.5, 2.5, 1.5, 0]    
...
```

I even tried something like

```
Matpreferences=[]  
    for i in range(10):  
    random.shuffle(vec)
    a=vec
    Matpreferences.append(a)
```

But it yields the same results. Is there any simple way to get around that?
Thanks a lot for any help given =)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, all the answers were great. I am not versed on computer science, so I didn't know that it was different to set v=vec or v=vec[:]
Gonna read more about that so I can understand this mechanism fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a copy of `vec` before you shuffle it:

```
import random
vec=[1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(5):
    vec.append(10)
Matpreferences=[]
for i in range(10):
    v = vec[:]
    random.shuffle(v)
    Matpreferences.append(v)
```

#### Explanation

From your code:

```
a=vec
Matpreferences.append(a)
```

Here, `a` points at the same data that `vec` points at.  Consequently, when `a` is shuffled, so is `vec` and so is everything that points at `vec`.

By contrast, because of the subscripting `[:]`, this code creates a new and independent copy of the data:

```
v = vec[:]
```

Because `v` is a separate and independent copy, shuffling `v` has no effect on `vec`.

Answer (score 3):

Your adding an object reference to the list. Think of it as a pointer. Each vec that you add to Matpreferences points to the same instance.

Look at this example:

```
>>> vec = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> vec2 = vec
>>> random.shuffle(vec)
>>> print vec
[2, 4, 3, 1, 5]
>>> print vec2
[2, 4, 3, 1, 5]
>>>
```

As you see, the content of `vec` and `vec2` is the same even though I did not shuffle `vec2`.

what you need to do is to copy the content of `vec` into a new list and then add that list to Matpreferences

Replace your last line with

```
Matpreferences.append([x for x in vec])
```

or

```
Matpreferences.append(vec[:])
```

Answer (score 1):

`random.shuffle` shuffles a list in place, so after each call, contents of `vec` gets shuffled. Note that `vec` is a reference to a list, so when you append `vec` 10 times in a list, it contains the same reference 10 times. All of them holds the same list. That's why you see the same list. `vec` is indeed shuffled 10 times, but you only see the last permutation when you print it.

To fix this, you'll need to make a new copy of vec each time, shuffle the copy and append that to `Matpreferences`. Or you can shuffle `vec`, then append a copy of it to `Matpreferences`.

Copying a list would be easy, the shortest one is, I think, using slicing:

```
Matpreferences.append(vec[:])
```